# Why would a process be showing an outbound connection from a 169.254 address when there's no unconfigured adapter?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, tcpip

I have a system that has several network adapters, only one of which is enabled. That adapter has ipv4 only enabled and it has a single IP address. It was previously part of a team. The team was broken while trying to fix another issue with the system. Now that it's back online with one nic and one IP address, some of the applications on the system are not working and when I use TCPview to see the connections the server is making I see that the applications in question are connecting on a local address of 169.254.x.x even though there are no unconfigured adapters. The applications that are working connect out via the hostname of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like those applications are trying to bind to the no-longer-existing NIC team, which is why they're picking up the link-local address.  "NIC" they're trying to use doesn't exist, therefore doesn't have an IP address, therefore generates a link-local address.

Comment: I might have to remove the devices entirely from the system, because again, they're already disabled. I can't imagine how an application is getting an auto configure address from a device it can't see anymore. There's no teaming configuration application running either. When I configure the enabled adapter, teaming is def disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was still some residual issue with the adapter being teamed. I disabled everything except the essential items in the connection properties:

Client for microsoft networks
IPV4
File and printer sharing

Rebooted the server and the TCPView no longer showed the strange connections.